# sum of items group by in pandas and writing in file

Tags: python, pandas

code used:

```
bytreatment = df.groupby(['QuoteID'])  
df2['numeric_sort_sum']= bytreatment['ComQuotePrice'].sum()
```

Input file:

```
id1 100
id1 200
id3 200
id3 300
id4 400
```

Result should be as follows:

```
id1 300
id1 300
id3 500
id3 500
id4 400
```

for me result comes as

```
id1 300
id3 500
id4 400
```

and i need to write this result in to file.. should i use loop and index

Answer (score 2):

To add a column generated from a `groupby` use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df2['numeric_sort_sum']= bytreatment['ComQuotePrice'].transform('sum')

In [22]:
df['numeric_sort_sum'] = df.groupby('QuoteID').transform('sum')
df

Out[22]:
  QuoteID  ComQuotePrice  numeric_sort_sum
0     id1            100               300
1     id1            200               300
2     id3            200               500
3     id3            300               500
4     id4            400               400
```

you can then call [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) on the above to write it ti file